# Facebook Login in Swift. "Unknown scheme received: authorize"

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.x

I'm new in Swift and I have to integrate the social network login (Facebook and Google) in an old app. This app will call as A.

First of all I created a new project to understand the both SDKs. This app will call as B

After understand the A app, without any problem, I went to B.

Trying to integrate the Facebook SDK when I run the app, I get this error:

> Unknown scheme received: authorize

Steps to get this error.

1. Click the Facebook login button
2. Enter my email and password
3. Accept the permissions
4. Accept to login in

The screen puts full white.
In B app, the Facebook login finishes, come back to my app and the Facebook Login Button, change to Logout.

When I did the steps in the SDK, for the B app, when I filled the Info.plist as Facebook says.

In

`B -> Info -> URL Types`

A new URL Type was created

When I did the same for A, fill the Info.plist in

`A -> Info -> URL Types`

A new URL Type was NOT created

Then I had to create it manually.

This is the Info.plist for A

[image]

This is the Info.plist for B

[image]

I think that the problem is here, but I don't know why.

- The A doesn't work
- The B works

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm bundle identifier of A and B are same or different.

if it is different then `have you added both app identifier in Facebook app configuration correctly?`

Comment: The bundle identifier of A and B are differents.
I've created two differents apps in Facebook developer

Comment: It is just a configuration issue, compare configurations done in App B with app A, info.plist file (URL Scheme)

Comment: Also, both app configurations at Facebook dev portal.

Comment: I 've compared the info.plist between A and B app. There isn't differences in "facebook" zone.

Also, I've checked the facebook console website, and the bundle identifier and the facebook id are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! The problem was to call the method

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool
```

and not to

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool
```